# Activate browser tab using HTML5 Notification

Tags: html, browser, notifications, web-notifications

I'm using the HTML5 [Notification API](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/) to show a message if new content is available. I'd like to show the browser tab that caused the notification to be activated when the user clicks the message, but I haven't been able to find an API to do so. I did find the [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/), but it only seems to send events when tabs change, not allow me to activate a tab.

Is it possible to control the browser like this, or is it simply not allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anything, `window.focus()` should do it from inside the notification's `click` event handler.

See https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/#activating-a-notification for details.